# Using a class hierarchy and mypy for static type testing

Tags: python, types, mypy

In the following example code I have a simple class hierarchy: `Thing->Bookmark`.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime
import rdflib
import json
import dateutil.parser

########### Class Hierarchy ##############ß
@dataclass
class Thing:
    ID: str

@dataclass
class Bookmark(Thing):
    creator: str
    description: str
    url: str
    created_on: datetime

########### Ports #################
class RepositoryInterface(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def save(self, data: Thing) -> str:
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def get_by_id(self, ID: str) -> Thing:
        pass

########### Adaptors ###############

class FileBasedBookmarkStore(RepositoryInterface):
    def save(self, data: Bookmark) -> str:
        with open(data.ID, "w") as f:
            dataJson = data.__dict__
            dataJson["created_on"] = data.created_on.isoformat()
            json.dump(data.__dict__, f)
            return data.ID

    def get_by_id(self, ID: str) -> Bookmark:
        with open(ID, "r") as f:
            jsonBookmark  = json.load(f)
            jsonBookmark["created_on"] = dateutil.parser.parse(jsonBookmark["created_on"])
            return Bookmark(**jsonBookmark)
```

My repository has an abstract class that is defined for `Thing` and then I implement a specific version for `Bookmark`.

`mypy` claims:

>
Argument 1 of "save" is incompatible with supertype "RepositoryInterface"; supertype defines the argument type as "Thing"

However, it has no problem with the return type for the `get_by_id` signature.

What is going here and how might I fix the type checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic types are your friends here.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
import json
import dateutil.parser

########### Class Hierarchy ##############ß
@dataclass
class Thing:
    ID: str

@dataclass
class Bookmark(Thing):
    creator: str
    description: str
    url: str
    created_on: datetime

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Thing)

########### Ports #################
class RepositoryInterface(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def save(self, data: T) -> str:
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def get_by_id(self, ID: str) -> T:
        pass

########### Adaptors ###############

class FileBasedBookmarkStore(RepositoryInterface[Bookmark]):
    def save(self, data: Bookmark) -> str:
        with open(data.ID, "w") as f:
            dataJson = data.__dict__
            dataJson["created_on"] = data.created_on.isoformat()
            json.dump(data.__dict__, f)
            return data.ID

    def get_by_id(self, ID: str) -> Bookmark:
        with open(ID, "r") as f:
            jsonBookmark  = json.load(f)
            jsonBookmark["created_on"] = dateutil.parser.parse(jsonBookmark["created_on"])
            return Bookmark(**jsonBookmark)
```

Comment: Many thanks. Does binding to Thing mean that only types on that hierarchy are recognised?

Comment: @user2302244 correct. It's documented here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds

Answer (score 0):

After finding [this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6248) on `github`, I changed the type signature in the abstract class to `Any`.

```
########### Ports #################
class RepositoryInterface(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def save(self, data: Any) -> str:
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def get_by_id(self, ID: str) -> Thing:
        pass
```

Most of the other references were saying that the earlier version was correctly flagged as a problem because of the Liskov Substitution Principle.

However, because the method is abstract and needs a concrete implementation having `Any` here seems ok to me.